# Python won't write file on Windows without IDLE

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, file-handling

I am trying to modify Google-Chrome's Preferences file with Python, but the code only works when run inside IDLE, not when run normally.

I am new to Python.
I use win10. The file-handling happens via `open`, `read`, `write` and `close`. The code works correctly when run from IDLE or cmd, but when I double-klick it, it pops up, runs and terminates without ever modifying the file.
It does not only not modify the Preferences file, but when I changed the code I couldn't even get it to write anything to any file by double-klicking the .py file (from IDLE I still could).

Comment: It's probably a path related error, and it's closing before you can see it. You could run the script from a `bat` file and put a `pause` at the end to see the error. If you're using a relative path though in the file operations, its probably that. Try switching to an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you. Tryed from `bat`, worked. Then tryed by double-klicking, worked. I do not know what solved the problem. Should I delete the question now?